Keycloak always returning 401 (unauthorized) when accessing admin console
I'm using Keycloak to manage access and profiles for some applications. Up until now, everything was fine, but a few days ago, I created a service account and changed some settings through the admin console. After that, I'm no longer able to access the web interface. Whenever I try to access it with any user, the application doesn't finish the login process and just keeps loading. When I checked the browser console, I saw that the error it's returning is a permission error 401. I believe that when I changed the settings for the service account, I changed some global configuration and now no user is able to access the admin console. I've tried to undo this by changing some table properties via the database, but I was unsuccessful. Does anyone know how I can re-enable access to the application interface?
Erro showing in my console:
POST https://mykeycloak.com/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token 401 (Unauthorized)
Thank you

Keycloak stores your configuration and the trace in <keycloak_installation_directory>->data->h2 directory. If you can open the trace.db file in a text editor like a Notepad++ and look at the trace log file, you should be able to see any errors.

The following message appears in the logs:
[org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-20) type="CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR", realmId="aa982226-7722-4415-9e34-b225b863ae63", realmName="master", clientId="security-admin-console", userId="null", ipAddress="xx.xx.x.xxx", error="invalid_client_credentials", grant_type="authorization_code"

Please see this link to see if this is your case: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/26896
